# Duplicated results when searching Android listview

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented searching option to ListView. First I get data by JSON and put them in ArrayList. Searching list is working fine when is loaded about 20 itmes, but I have to load about 550+ items and give user option to search desired one. Loading that amount of item is working fine but searching doesn't work properly. If user type something that exist in list the final result is list that shows desired item but listed three times in row. How is that possible? Is it problem if list contains so much items?

Comment: Are you sure your adapter contains only distinct values?

Comment: Yes, all values in table are unique.

Comment: Hm... very interesting. I've tried now on other computer. Same version of Java Eclipse, SDK... everything and on that computer works fine. Now I'm confused.